# Не удаляются дочерние таблицы SQLite

Tags: node.js, sqlite

sqlite3 на node js

У меня есть 3 таблицы:

```
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  firstName varchar(30),
  lastName varchar(50),
  email varchar(150),
  phone varchar(12),
  address varchar(255),
  photo varchar(255),
  hash varchar(255),
  token varchar(255)
)`);
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS advert (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  idUser integer,
  title varchar(255),
  date datetime,
  price double,
  category varchar(50),
  description text(2000),
  mainImage varchar(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)`);
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favorites (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  idUser integer,
  idAdvert integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (idAdvert) REFERENCES advert(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)`);
```

При удалении пользователя:

```
db.run(`
  DELETE
  FROM user
  WHERE id = ?
`, [id], function(error) {
  ...
});
```

Удаляется пользователь, но не удаляются дочерние таблицы.
Если тоже самое делаю в sqlitebrowser, то все работает. Почему так?

Comment: `PRAGMA foreign_keys;`?

Comment: Нет, это не добавлял. Не понял как и куда

Comment: @PetSerAl, а разве `PRAGMA foreign_keys` не только при добавлении/изменении играет роль?

Comment: @Fat-Zer или @PetSerAl подскажите плз как использовать `PRAGMA foreign_keys`, я хотя бы попробую. Нигде не нашел, как указывать это с nodejs

Comment: Все, `PRAGMA` помогло, спасибо